# Difference between "I was being careless" and "I was careless"

Tags: expressions

Is there any significant difference between saying

> I am/was **being** *adj*. (careless, busy, etc)...

*[treating "am/was" as an auxiliary verb]*

and

> I am/was *adj.* (careless, busy, etc)...

Personally, I consider adding the word *being* a bit fussy but is there actually an effect of doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of "being" implies a reference to a specific event or context.

> In my youth, I was careless.

The above makes sense, but the following does not:

> In my youth, I was being careless.

The same applies to your second example. "I am being careless" implies carelessness in reference to a specific situation or act, whereas "I am careless" implies a more general observation, perhaps to ones character.

Comment: Great answer!! I don't find the second expression senseless though. There is a slight humor in it.

Comment: If I were to attempt to use the latter phrase, I would probably clarify it with a specific event.

Answer (score 3):

*Being* in this case means *behaving*, which could be translated to *behaving carelessly*. Your second example describes a more like a habitual action.

> He is being selfish. This means that he is behaving selfishly at this period of time.
>
> He is selfish. This means that he is a selfish person.

Answer (score 2):

- `I am careless` means it your *habit* to be careless.
- `I am being careless` means you *are being* careless with whatever you are doing right now (e.g., carrying a cup full of coffee, handling a case - police case, etc.). It doesn't guarantee that you are always careless.
- `I was careless` means your were careless with something (or everything; it's ambiguous) in the *past*.
- `I was being careless` means you were being careless with something (or everything; it's ambiguous) in the *past*.

Comment: I'd argue that "I am being busy" is valid in certain ways, e.g. in the context of avoiding someone: "I am being busy on purpose, so that he doesn't bother me."

Comment: @Polynomial Missed that one in haste. Edit made.

Answer (score 0):

You're right in saying that the Stative Verb "Be" is not often used in "V+ing" form.

But in this case, it's particularly important to use it this way because "Be + being" means "acting or behaving in a particular way."

There would be a very big difference between: "He was stupid." (generally) and: "He was being stupid" (only at the moment, he isn't usually like that).

So, if you say "I was being careless," you are **emphasizing** the fact that you aren't always like that.

(Although I'd also prefer to say something like: "That was me being careless.")

Comment: I have to add that "Be Being" isn't always possible. Ex. I was being tired/ busy = X

Comment: "Being busy" is valid. See my comment on rudra's answer. I can't see how "being tired" is valid, though, since it's an involuntary state.

Comment: I get what you mean by "being busy." But I took into account ArchJ's exposure to the concept of "Be Verb in V+ing form," and decided to leave it for another lesson. Thanks for the comment